# Active Directory Custom Search LDAP query

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am trying to do an LDAP query in component services where I would find all the groups in a specific Organizational Unit

I've tried this and many other things but it never seems to work.

```
(objectCategory=group)(ou=david test*)
```

Can anyone please help me. I've searched online for a while now and found nothing

Thank you
Gibit

Comment: I am trying to do it in Component Services, in the Find:CustomSearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LDAP query just have to specify 
(objectClass=group)

Recall : A LDAP query is

1. The nod from which you ask to begin the search (in your case the DN of your OU)
2. The scope of your search (base, onelevel, subtree)
3. The filter of your search ((objectClass=group))
4. The attributes you want to retreive

This is what you'll find in an LDAP URL and in most of the APIs in any language.

```
ldap://Hote:port/base_dn?attributs?scope?filter
```

I hope it helps

JP

Comment: I am not sure I understand... It should be something like this ? (objectCategory=group)(objectClass=group)(ou=david test*)

Comment: NO the filterjust have to be "objectClass=group". And the search have to begin in the OU you are searching. What are you using for your search ?

Comment: You should use `objectCategory` instead of `objectClass` since the category is single-valued and indexed (while object class isn't)

Comment: Why multi valued, versus singled valued is a criterion. If we will check definition of objectCategory in schema we will see that it is DN, and in correct format for LDAP filter we should use full DN for object class we are willing to use. Active Directory search engine simplifies this task a little and it allows usage of LDAP display name of class in such filter (objectCategory=CN=Group,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,...). For me objectCategory helps in filters in order to distinguish, user versus computer objects for examples that both have (objectClass=user).

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention what is the operation for these criteria and/or

If its or

> (|(objectCategory=group)(ou=david test*))

It will try to find all the object either with objectcategory group or an organizational unit starting with 'david test' from the root.

If its and

> (&(objectCategory=group)(ou=david test*))

It won't find anything because an organizational unit object category wont be a group.

Instead what you can do is, set the base dn as ou=david test,...
and just search for 'objectCategory=group'.

If you dont know the organizational unit dn, do a first search with the filter (ou=david test*) and get the dn and set it as base dn for the next search and now search for 'objectCategory=group'